# $G$-parity in an electromagnetic decay

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, interactions, parity

I am looking at the decay $\eta\rightarrow\pi^+\pi^-\gamma$ and I would assume that the decay itself (ignoring the $\pi\pi$ final state interaction that is obviously strong) is electromagnetic since there is a photon involved. In a paper by Stollenwerk et al. on this decay they write that the partial wave of the pion pair is dominated by $1^{--}$. I assume this means that only odd partial waves contribute and that the F wave is already suppressed enough to be neglected. I can only explain this via [$G$-parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-parity) conservation, which would yield a photon isospin of $1$ and consequently $I_{\pi\pi}=1$, but for an apparently electromagnetic process I cannot see why that should apply.

So my actual questions:

a) Is there any way a process involving a photon can be strong?

b) Are there types of electromagnetic processes for which $G$-parity is conserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sure hope I could get into details but I will be straightforward.

---

a) Is there any way a process involving a photon can be strong?

I suppose you mean "strong" in a phenomenological description of the processes involved. In a loose way of speaking they could be similar if you restrict yourself to discussing conservation of certain quantities e.g. **total** Isospin, parity, etc, however it is the fact that these can be considered somehow "accidental" what makes them different in a general playground. The process you describe is an example of this.

---

b) Are there types of electromagnetic processes for which G-parity is conserved?

Of course, behind this there are two important facts. The first is:

> Non-conservation of a property doesn't mean violation under all circumstances.

while the second is:

> G-parity relates a rotation in Isospin space ($R_T$) and charge conjugation ($C$).

Electromagnetic interaction is already $C$-invariant so what you could ask, for G-parity to be conserved in the end, is if the process you're studying is invariant under the Isospin rotation involved. I happened to find your question while looking for something related to a problem in Fayyazuddin's "A modern introduction to particle physics". There you can check that:
$$
|\pi^{\pm}\rangle \xrightarrow{R_T} |\pi^{\mp}\rangle
$$
$$
|\pi^{0}\rangle \xrightarrow{R_T} |\pi^{0}\rangle
$$

since $\eta$ (interaction eigenstate) is a singlet you should have similarly $|\eta\rangle \xrightarrow{R_T} |\eta\rangle$. The photon part may seem trivial but remember that in general a photon may be considered to be a superposition of a $I=0$ and a $I=1$ contribution (do not confuse with EW Isospin). If however you could justify $|\gamma\rangle \xrightarrow{R_T} |\gamma\rangle$ the exercise would be over (this is part of my homework) and G-parity conservation would be a reasonable tool to use.